# Is it possible to do "call by reference when possible" in C++?

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

Is it possible to ask the complier to use the "call-by-reference" version of a function when possible? I wish to avoid "copy" as much as possible

For example, I have a function `fooCallByValue(myObj x)` and `fooCallByReference(myObj& x)`. They have identical implementation but I **really** wish to use call-by-reference whenever possible for some reason. Currently I have to manually choose which function to call. Simply have two functions with the same name (e.g.  `foo(myObj x)` and `foo(myObj& x)`) will cause an error (Using a template doesn't help either).

Example **problematic** code:

```
class myObj {
public:
myObj(myObj& obj) {
    // implementation...
}
myObj& operator = (myObj& obj) {
    // implementation...
}

myObj operator + (myObj& obj) {
    // implementation...
}
  // other members and implementation...

   someObj* pointer;
};


void foo(myObj& x) {
    cout << "call by reference" << endl;
}

void foo(myObj x) {
    cout << "call by value" << endl;
}

int main() {
    myObj x, y;

    //init x and y...

    foo(x);
    foo(x + y);
}
```

Desired output:

```
call by reference
call by value
```

Thanks in advance.

Edits:

1. For some special reason `operator +` is going modify the input `myObj& x` so it is not taking in a constant.

Yes it is desire to modify the original input when possible. Otherwise it will do a "copy" and modify the copied value.

2. More backgrounds:

This `myObj` contains a pointer. Therefore I need to do a deep-copy in copy constructor. But I don't want to do that when passing values between functions when possible.

Comment: FYI, `operator +` should be returning a new object, not a reference.

Comment: Should also be taking a const reference.

Comment: "I wish to avoid "copy" as much as possible" - remember that passing by value will often enable *move*.

Comment: I'm kinda curious how you manage to implement `myObj& operator + (myObj& obj)` in a way that doesn't trigger undefined behavior. What do you return?

Comment: What is the issue with passing by value?  You wrote the function to take a value -- nothing forced you to implement that function.  In C++, you get what you pay for, and you paid for a function that takes `myObj` by value.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out!

Comment: What does `foo` do exactly?  If inside `foo`, you make a copy of the passed-in value anyway, then passing by-value is more efficient, since the compiler's optimizer may step in and do its work.  Your function would then work exclusively with the argument instead of manually making a copy of it.  As a matter of fact, many C++ programmers implement the copy / swap idiom for `operator =` with a passed-by-value argument instead of a const reference, due to having the compiler take advantage of optimization opportunities.

Comment: More background information added

Comment: @RuiyuZhu Note that `x + y` returns a temp object, so `foo(x + y)` will not be able to call `foo(myObj& x)` because a temp object can't bind to a non-const reference. But it can call `foo(myObj x)`, as well as `foo(const myObj& x)` and `foo(myObj&& x)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean to distinguish between r-values and l-values. You can do that with these overloads.

```
void foo(myObj& x) {
    cout << "call by l-value" << endl;
}

void foo(myObj&& x) {
    cout << "call by r-value" << endl;
}
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/NrUqdW)

Comment: Yes, I am trying to find a way to distinguish between r-values and l-values.